# Why mvn effective pom contains dependencies that are not in mvn dependency tree

Tags: maven

In a maven project, in order to locate where a maven dependency is imported, I used mvn dependency tree, however, I cannot find this jar in its output.
From mvn effective-pom output, I can see this jar.

What is the difference between mvn dependency tree and effective-pom, why the latter shows jar that are not in the former one.

both commands are run in bash.